# excel vba + hyperlink to other workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have workbookA, I run a macro which copy information from workbookA to workbookB. I want to add a hyperlink for every row (so I can find where this row is in workbookA). But I can't get it to work. In the same workbook but different sheets it works.

My code:

```
Set rw = sh.rows(i)
Set targetCell = rw.Cells(1, "R")
wbB.Sheets("Sheet1").Hyperlinks.add Anchor:=rng.EntireRow.Cells(1, "A"), Address:="", SubAddress:="='" & sh.name & "'!" & targetCell.Address & "", TextToDisplay:="Link"
```

Tx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the hyperlink to open a different workbook, you should do something like:

```
wbB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wbB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 1), Address:="Your.xlsm", SubAddress:="Sheet1!A10", TextToDisplay:="Link"
```

Where your Anchor is where the link should be placed in your worksheet, address is the name of your workbook to be opened and SubAddress is the Sheet and range that should be selected when opened.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. So everything before Hyperlinks is about the new workbook (workbookB) and the address and subaddress is the information from workbookA?

Comment: Everything before the Hyperlinks, is where you will initiate the command to add a hyperlink, the anchor is where it will be placed, the address is the workbook to link to and the subaddress is the Sheet and range you want to select after clicking the link...